# UIScrollView showing subview not correctly

Tags: swift

I'm trying to show simple custom view into scrollView. Here's my code :

```
struct scrollViewDataStruct {
    let title: String?
    let image: UIImage?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

     var scrollViewData = [scrollViewDataStruct]()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         scrollViewData = [
         scrollViewDataStruct(title: "First", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iPhone 8 Copy 2")),
        scrollViewDataStruct(title: "Second", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iPhone 8 Copy 3"))
    ]
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(scrollViewData.count)
    var i = 0
    for _ in scrollViewData {
        let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))
        self.scrollView.addSubview(view)
        i += 1
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

}

class CustomView: UIView {

let imageView: UIImageView = {
   let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return imageView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}    
}
```

As you can see, the `CustomView's frame = scrollView's frame` but when i ran application it's not as I expected : 
[image]

Then, in storyboard, i change device from iphone8 to iphone 8 plus and run again. It's show `CustomView` correctly. I have no idea, the `scrollView` is always correct but the `CustomView` is not .
Any suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accessing the `frame` of the scrollView before *Auto Layout* has run and established the size of the `frame` for the actual device.  A quick fix is to move your setup code into an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
You have to be careful though, because unlike `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will run more than once, so you have to make sure you don't add your views multiple times.

```
// property - have we set up the views yet?
var setup = false

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if !setup {
        scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(scrollViewData.count)
        var i = 0
        for _ in scrollViewData {
            let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))
            self.scrollView.addSubview(view)
            i += 1
        }
        setup = true
    }
}
```

You should consider using constraints to place your views within your scrollView content instead of messing with the `frame` calculations, then *Auto Layout* would just automatically do the right thing.

Comment: Keeping a new object for set a flag is not good idea, even view lifecycle calls `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` many times. For best practices we should use `autoresizingMask` property for this.

Answer (score 0):

> In viewDidLoad, UI component will suppose to have the size you have taken in storyboard.

There are 2 ways to do this:

**1. Use `autoresizingMask` property**

autoresizingMask property will resize the view, if its containerView's frames changed

```
    var i = 0
    for _ in scrollViewData {
        let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))
        view.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
        self.scrollView.addSubview(view)
        i += 1
    }
```

**2. Use fixed parameters, say `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height`**

Just update your code for custom view's height with reference to screen height rather than scroll view's height. It will work fine

```
    var i = 0
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    for _ in scrollViewData {
        let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: height))
        self.scrollView.addSubview(view)
        i += 1
    }
```

Comment: But i just want my CustomView fit to scrollView not screen

Comment: Here your scrollview's height is of full screen. My point was to keep your custom view's height with respect to screen height rather than scroll view. If custom view is not full screen's height then we can go with `autoresizingMask` property as well. See updated answer